# Bounding singular values of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, upper-lower-bounds, singular-values

Let $M,N \in \mathbb{N}$ and matrices $A\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$, $B\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times M}$, $C\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$. We are interested on the maximal singular value of the matrix
\begin{equation}
P = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where we can choose the $(N\times M)$ matrix $D$.

Is there a choice of $D$ that minimizes or upper bounds the maximal singular value of the matrix $P$ ?

Comment: What kind of upper bounds do you have in mind? Absolute upper bounds won't apply, but you could come up with upper bounds in terms of the singular values of $A,B,C$

Comment: Yes I would say an upper bound involving A,B and C (maybe D I dont if it could make sense)

Comment: For one upper bound, we could note that 
$$
\sigma_{\max}(P) \leq \sigma_{\max}(A) + \sigma_{\max}(B) + \sigma_{\max}(C) + \sigma_{\max}(D).
$$
Selecting $D$ such that $\sigma_{\max}(D) \leq \sigma_{\max}(A)$, as an example, would lead to the upper bound $2\sigma_{\max}(A) + \sigma_{\max}(B) + \sigma_{\max}(C)$.

Comment: Therefore, the best choice of $D$ suggested by your inequality is D such that $\sigma_{\max}(D) = 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, but there is no guarantee that this $D$ actually yields the smallest maximal singular value for $P$